# CryptoJS AES encryption and PHP decryption with cookies

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to use CryptoJS to encrypt with AES and decrypt using in PHP.

Here is the code I'm using for JS e. All encoded data is written to cookie

```
Cookie.write = function (key, value, duration) {
    value=encrypt(value);
    Cookie.remove(key);
    var d = new Date();
    if (duration <= 0)
        duration = 1;
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * duration);
    document.cookie = key + "=" + encodeURI(value) + "; expires=" + d.toGMTString() + ";path=/";
};

function encrypt(word)
{
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("010216a654976158");
    var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("010216a654976158");
    var src = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(word);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(src, key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
    });
    return encrypted.toString();
}

function decrypt(word)
{
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("010216a654976158");
    var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("010216a654976158");
    var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(word, key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, 
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
    });
    return CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decrypt).toString();
}
```

Now here is the php code that I'm using

```
$uidE = $_COOKIE["uid"];
$decode = base64_decode($uidE);
$pk ="010216a654976158";
$iv ="010216a654976158";
$value = '4';

$encrypted = ( mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $pk, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv) );

$uid = (mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $pk, $decode, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv));

echo base64_encode($encrypted);
```

This is what I get:

> 0rHkBQo88rYhLP0qjIBeSQ==

I don't know why but when I use the value of 4 to encode using JS and write
'0rHkBQo88rYhLP0qjIBeSQ==' to cookie I have no problems decoding using php.

If I use any other number, the decoded value of `$uid` is unreadable,
but if I change `$value` to that number I can decode no problem.

Comment: I have the problem, when I'm using 4 to encode there is no + in the string written to cookie thus I had no problems decoding. When I use 10 to encode I get soP4qTrlIZhiI+kIot0VuQ==, but when I use $_COOKIE, the value I get is soP4qTrlIZhiI kIot0VuQ==, with the + omitted, that is why I can't decode.

Comment: my temporary solution is to add `$uidE = str_replace(' ','+',$uidE);`